# Quasar q-uploader not working with given url path

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

q-uploader, i follow it well but still not working

in youtube  and q-uploader api, i think i follow it correctly but it is not working right.

in youtube tutorial this how it works with them

```
<q-uploader
      url="http://localhost/TAARA/backend/taara_backend/API/animale_image"
      dark
      auto-upload
    />
```

with q-uploader api

```
<q-uploader
      url="http://localhost:8080/TAARA/backend/taara_backend/API/animale_image"
      dark
      auto-upload
    />
```

need specify the port

the result without port 8080, it's not uploading and the response is

```
cannot post TAARA/backend/taara_backend/API/animale_image
```

but with 8080 port in frontend its uploading 99.99% but not 100% so still not uploaded, and the response is the same

```
cannot post TAARA/backend/taara_backend/API/animale_image
```

im thinking what's really the problem and if q-uploader is still working today.